# How can i get TextMate-in-QuickLook plugin to display all file types

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, plugins, textmate

i have downloaded [TextMate in QuickLook](http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/11/15/quicklook-and-textmate) plugin
I displays, for example .sh, .h files, but .txt, .cpp and others - does't
How can i tweak it ?
I really like "Pastels on Dark" Theme and want to display with it all the "textual" files of all types :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select one file with the extension you want (for example .sh).

Do "Get Info" in Finder.

Then setup Finder to 'Open with' all files with this extension with TextMate.